# Matlab char to double vector

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, vector

Is there an easy way to convert a char array to a vector?
for example, 
I have this

my_array = <1*64 char>

and it is full of "1010101010..."

I want it to be:

my_vector = [1 0 1 0 1 0....]

is there any function that makes it possible without me writing any code? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str='01001011';
[str2num(str(:))]'

ans =

     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     1
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Good point. I guess I just put them in out of habit, for those rare cases where they are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_vector = double(my_array - '0');
```